# GtkTreeView hook interactive-search dialog

Tags: c, gtk, gtk2, gtktreeview

Is there a way to hook the interactive-search dialog in such a way that I handle what happens when the user types text in it? I want to hook it so I can implement interactive filtering instead of searching.

I'll use GtkTreeModelFilter over a list-store, and I'll call `gtk_tree_model_filter_refilter()` each time the user types or deletes a symbol in the interactive search box.

I imagine something like this pseudo-code:

```
void on_search_box_text_changed(gchar *new_text)
{
     set_filter_text(new_text);
     GtkTreeModelFilter *filter = ...;
     gtk_tree_model_filter_refilter(filter);
}
```

If it works, it would look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4DIE.gif).